# how to test javascript chain of promises?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript promise similar to this:

```
function a(){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    b().then(function(result){
        if(result.name == 'sampletest1'){
            resolve({
                'data': 'testdata1'
            });
        }else if(result.name=='sampletest2'){
            resolve({
                'data': 'testdata2'
            });
        }
    }, reject);
})
}
```

I want to write test in jasmine to test functionality of function `a`. But I am having trouble as this function is dependent on the result of function `b`, which is also a promise. So, how to mock function `b` , so that I would be able to test functionality of function `a`.

Comment: That looks like an anti-pattern, you probably want to write it as `function a() {return b().then(...)}` since `b` returns a promise, and instead of `resolve` you `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not return an extra promise:

```
function a() {

  return b().then(function(result) {
    if (result.name == 'sampletest1') {
      return {
        'data': 'testdata1'
      };
    } else if (result.name == 'sampletest2') {
      return {
        'data': 'testdata2'
      };
    }
  });

}
```

Mocking `b` would be as simple as:

```
b = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        resolve({ name: 'sampletest1' });
    });
};
```